# Determine the convergence of the improper integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

[This is link to question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xfxz.png)
[Here is my attempt, but the answer key is convergent. I dont think I count it wrong.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAcEs.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Since the integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+\sqrt x}$ diverges, you cannot deduce from the fact that $(\forall x\in[1,\infty)):\frac{\sin(1/x)}{2+\sqrt x}\leqslant\frac1{2+\sqrt x}$ that your integral converges.

Comment: To make the incorrect thought clearer, just because for all positive integer $n$ we have $0 < \frac1n < n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} n = \infty$ it does **not** follow that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n = \infty$. In other words, showing that something is smaller than something that diverges to $\infty$ does not tell you anything about the convergence or divergence of the "smaller" series.

Comment: @Ingix Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \frac{\sin(1/x)}{2+\sqrt{x}} \sim \frac{1/x}{2+\sqrt{x}} \sim \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Moreover, $f(x) \geq 0 $ for $x$ sufficiently large.

Therefore, $\int_1^{+\infty} f(x) dx $ converges since $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}} dx$ converges.

Comment: Thank you. Good job

Comment: You can actually replace those $\sim$ signs with $\lt$ signs, since $\sin\theta\lt\theta$ for $\theta\gt0$.